# iphone CoreTelephony and .mm file

Tags: iphone, ios, core-telephony, ussd

I am using CoreTelephony to make a call to USSD number (I know it is not officially supported, but that doesn't matter right now). I've added a framework to project, imported all headers:

```
#import<CoreTelephony/CTCallCenter.h>    
#import<CoreTelephony/CTCall.h>   
#import<CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>    
#import<CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>
```

However, when I make call to `CTCallDialWithID` function, I get compiler error: "Use of undeclared identifier 'CTCallDialWithID'. Since I have some C++ code, my controller file is declared as .mm file. If I rename it to .m, call works fine.
Why is this happening and how do I fix it?